# PHP: Checking if x-www-form-urlencoded parameter is null

Tags: php, post

I am trying to parse a POST (x-www-form-urlencoded) request which includes an array like this:

[image]

Now, when I loop through that:

```
$arr = $_POST["fieldvalue"];

foreach($arr as $key => $value)
{
    if(empty($value) || is_null($value))
    {
        echo "Something in the array is null";
    }
}
```

The echo-line is never done, because `$value` is actually `"null"` and not `null`.

That array may contain any type of value, like strings, integers, booleans, floats, ... so I don't think I can just do `if($value === "null")`, which does work in this example.

What I am trying to get at is that how do I parse that POST-data like so that all the `"null"` values get converted to proper `null` values, so that I can properly check for nulls?

Comment: Everything in the POST is text

Comment: IFAIK POST data only supports string data type.

Comment: What would be the preferrable way to be then? Should I be sending type for each value as well?